# apache servers not sending data after glibc update

Tags: centos6, apache-2.4, glibc

I have an apache download server that I recently performed a botched install of a new version of glibc on, and now I only get 'no data received' when attempting to retrieve files.
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Unix)

I'm running CentOS Linux 6.6, installed glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64 via rpm, as at the time a networking error meant yum was not functioning. /var/log/httpd/error_log shows:

> [Thu Jan 29 13:10:33.503125 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 12058] [client
>   10.8.1.133:52077] AH01215: (2)No such file or directory: exec of `'/var/www/cgi-bin/<file that it's attempting to retrieve>.exe`

'
repeated constantly, and wget returns:

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received. Retrying.

I think I've fixed the glibc installation and all the missing dependencies, but why is it no longer finding the files? I've checked and ensured that the file is there and has the correct permissions, but I can't seem to get the server to retrieve files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into your Apache configuration files?  If possible, compare your httpd.conf and related files to a recent backup just before your glibc fiasco.

In particular, it seems odd that a request for a file download is being sent to your cgi-bin directory.  Try looking at the "Directory", "Alias", and "ScriptAlias" directives in your setup.